How to add nginx memcached module to a production nginx reverse proxy?
Hey guys is there a way to add the memcached module to my nginx installation without reinstalling nginx?
Based on what you can see bellow, the module is not present...
# nginx -V 2>&1 | tr -- - '\n' | grep _module
http_ssl_module
http_v2_module
http_realip_module
http_addition_module
http_xslt_module=dynamic
http_image_filter_module=dynamic
http_sub_module
http_dav_module
http_flv_module
http_mp4_module
http_gunzip_module
http_gzip_static_module
http_random_index_module
http_secure_link_module
http_degradation_module
http_slice_module
http_stub_status_module
http_perl_module=dynamic
http_auth_request_module
mail_ssl_module
stream_ssl_module


AFAIK you have to download the same nginx version and compile the module you need. After successful compilation, you can add the *.so (module "file") to your current nginx instance

It depends on how you installed nginx originally, and what is your distribution. Many distributions do bundle different nginx modules as packages.
If your distribution has module available as a package, then you can install the package and configure nginx to use it and then restart nginx.

I'm using RHEL 8.9. I don't know how it was installed (the person who did it doesn't work here anymore), but I'm pretty sure it was via yum or dnf.

Then you should check RHEL8.9 packages to see if the required module is available and install it.
